# Putting listingsutf8 literate definitions in a separate file with \input

Tags: pdftex, listings, unicode

I have a set of `literate` options for the `listings` package that I would like to move to an external file, so I don't have to paste them in every time. (The eventual goal is to have LaTeX commands corresponding to all the ["LaTeX-like" shortcuts](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/latex_symbols.py) in ipython, which weighs in at over 1000 definitions!)

The following MWE compiles fine for me under pdflatex from MikTeX 2.9:

**`literate_mwe1.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    extendedchars=true,
    literate={Γ}{{\(\Gamma\)}}1 {Δ}{{\(\Delta\)}}1 {Θ}{{\(\Theta\)}}1 {Λ}{{\(\Lambda\)}}1 {Ξ}{{\(\Xi\)}}1 {Π}{{\(\Pi\)}}1 {Σ}{{\(\Sigma\)}}1 {Υ}{{\(\Upsilon\)}}1 {Φ}{{\(\Phi\)}}1 {Ψ}{{\(\Psi\)}}1 {Ω}{{\(\Omega\)}}1 {α}{{\(\alpha\)}}1 {β}{{\(\beta\)}}1 {γ}{{\(\gamma\)}}1 {δ}{{\(\delta\)}}1 {ζ}{{\(\zeta\)}}1 {η}{{\(\eta\)}}1 {θ}{{\(\theta\)}}1 {ι}{{\(\iota\)}}1 {κ}{{\(\kappa\)}}1 {λ}{{\(\lambda\)}}1 {μ}{{\(\mu\)}}1 {ν}{{\(\nu\)}}1 {ξ}{{\(\xi\)}}1 {π}{{\(\pi\)}}1 {ρ}{{\(\rho\)}}1 {ς}{{\(\varsigma\)}}1 {σ}{{\(\sigma\)}}1 {τ}{{\(\tau\)}}1 {υ}{{\(\upsilon\)}}1 {φ}{{\(\varphi\)}}1 {χ}{{\(\chi\)}}1 {ψ}{{\(\psi\)}}1 {ω}{{\(\omega\)}}1 {ϑ}{{\(\vartheta\)}}1 {ϕ}{{\(\phi\)}}1 {ϖ}{{\(\varpi\)}}1 {ϰ}{{\(\varkappa\)}}1 {ϱ}{{\(\varrho\)}}1 {ϴ}{{\(\varTheta\)}}1 {ϵ}{{\(\epsilon\)}}1
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{literate_test.txt}

\end{document}
```

where the referenced input listing is

**`literate_test.txt`**

```
ΓΔΘΛΞΠΣΥΦΨΩαβγδζηθικλμνξπρςστυφχψωϑϕϖϰϱϴϵ
```

Most of the documentation I can find, including this [great TeX SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32058/235983), says that the `\input` command just pastes the input file verbatim into the current file where the command is. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. If I try the seemingly identical example below,

**`literate_mwe2.tex`**

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    extendedchars=true,
    literate=\input{literate.tex}
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{literate_test.txt}

\end{document}
```

**`literate.tex`**

```tex
{Γ}{{\(\Gamma\)}}1 {Δ}{{\(\Delta\)}}1 {Θ}{{\(\Theta\)}}1 {Λ}{{\(\Lambda\)}}1 {Ξ}{{\(\Xi\)}}1 {Π}{{\(\Pi\)}}1 {Σ}{{\(\Sigma\)}}1 {Υ}{{\(\Upsilon\)}}1 {Φ}{{\(\Phi\)}}1 {Ψ}{{\(\Psi\)}}1 {Ω}{{\(\Omega\)}}1 {α}{{\(\alpha\)}}1 {β}{{\(\beta\)}}1 {γ}{{\(\gamma\)}}1 {δ}{{\(\delta\)}}1 {ζ}{{\(\zeta\)}}1 {η}{{\(\eta\)}}1 {θ}{{\(\theta\)}}1 {ι}{{\(\iota\)}}1 {κ}{{\(\kappa\)}}1 {λ}{{\(\lambda\)}}1 {μ}{{\(\mu\)}}1 {ν}{{\(\nu\)}}1 {ξ}{{\(\xi\)}}1 {π}{{\(\pi\)}}1 {ρ}{{\(\rho\)}}1 {ς}{{\(\varsigma\)}}1 {σ}{{\(\sigma\)}}1 {τ}{{\(\tau\)}}1 {υ}{{\(\upsilon\)}}1 {φ}{{\(\varphi\)}}1 {χ}{{\(\chi\)}}1 {ψ}{{\(\psi\)}}1 {ω}{{\(\omega\)}}1 {ϑ}{{\(\vartheta\)}}1 {ϕ}{{\(\phi\)}}1 {ϖ}{{\(\varpi\)}}1 {ϰ}{{\(\varkappa\)}}1 {ϱ}{{\(\varrho\)}}1 {ϴ}{{\(\varTheta\)}}1 {ϵ}{{\(\epsilon\)}}1
```

it causes the compiler to scream `Improper alphabetic constant.` at me twice from somewhere within the depths of the `listings` package, breaking some internal function `\lst@CDefIt`, and then overflowing the TeX stack at `\@@input "literate_test.txt"`.

[image: Errors from TeXStudio]

Other things I've tried include

- Putting the `literate=` inside `literate.tex`, which causes the compiler to emit `Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Γ (U+0393)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. literate={Γ`, which is similar to [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147780/235983](this TeX SE question), except both files have the *same* input encoding!
- Doing `{\inputencoding{utf8}\input{literate.tex}}`, which emits the same errors
- Putting `inputencoding{utf8}` inside `literate.tex`, which emits the same errors

What's going on here that prevents `\input` from inputting the file verbatim?

EDIT: The problem is solved by putting the entire `\lstset` in its own file. I still have no clue why this is happening though!

Comment: putting the whole \lstset in the external file is the right thing, \input is a bit more complicated thing then you might think, e.g. it is not expandable.

Comment: So the issues might be related to this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43007/235983

Comment: a bit, but today the situation is even more complicated as files hooks have been added to \input.